# Solve double pendulum problem with Laplace transformation

Tags: python, sympy

I have a problem that exceeds my limits, and I would appreciate if some of you could help me.
The problem is the following:I need to visualize the movement of a double-pendulum. We know the equation of the pendulums, and we also have the information that if the two angles are really small, then they will be in a form such as on the picture below(sin,cos). So I have to transform the original equation knowing that the sin and cos will get those values.
I have to solve the final equation system with Laplace-transformation, knowing that m1=3,m2=1,l1=l2=16, θ1(0) = 1, θ2(0) = −1, θ'1(0)=0, θ'2(0)=0.
My personal problem is that I dont know the way I could solve it with Laplace.

Equation

[image]

Sin and cos values

[image]

This is how far I got so far(It doesnt really give me the desired result):

```
import sympy as sympy
import numpy as np
from sympy.integrals.transforms import laplace_transform
from sympy.integrals.transforms import inverse_laplace_transform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def laplace_transform_derivatives(e):
    if isinstance(e, (sympy.Add, sympy.Mul)):
        t = type(e)
        return t(*[laplace_transform_derivatives(arg) for arg in e.args])
    if isinstance(e, sympy.LaplaceTransform):

        if isinstance(e.args[0], sympy.Derivative):
            d, t, s = e.args
            n = d.args[1][1]
            return ((s**n) * sympy.LaplaceTransform(d.args[0], t, s) - 
                    sum([s**(n-i) * sympy.diff(d.args[0], t, i-1).subs(t, 0)
                         for i in range(1, n+1)]))


    return e
def Laplace():
    m1=3
    m2=1
    l1=16
    l2=16
    g=9.8
    s, F= sympy.symbols("s, F", real=True)  
    t = sympy.symbols("t", positive=True)
    y1 = sympy.Function("y1")
    y2 = sympy.Function("y2")
    ode = (m1+m2)*(l1**2)*sympy.diff(y1(t), t, 2) + m2*l1*l2*sympy.diff(y2(t), t, 2)+m2*l1*l2*(sympy.diff(y2(t), t, 1)**2)+(m1+m2)*l1*g*y1(t)
    sympy.Eq(ode)
    L_y = sympy.laplace_transform(y2(t), t, s) 
    L_ode = sympy.laplace_transform(ode, t, s, noconds=True)
    sympy.Eq(L_ode)
    L_ode_2 = laplace_transform_derivatives(L_ode)
    sympy.Eq(L_ode_2)
    L_ode_3 = L_ode_2.subs(L_y, F)
    sympy.Eq(L_ode_3)
    kf = {y2(0): 1, y2(t).diff(t).subs(t, 0): 0}
    L_ode_4 = L_ode_3.subs(kf)
    sympy.Eq(L_ode_4)
    Y_sol = sympy.solve(L_ode_4, F) #kiszamitja az F-t
    y_sol = sympy.inverse_laplace_transform(Y_sol[0], s, t)
    sympy.simplify(y_sol)
    print(y_sol)
    return y_sol
def Laplace2():
    m2=1
    l1=16
    l2=16
    g=9.8
    s, F= sympy.symbols("s, F", real=True)  
    t = sympy.symbols("t", positive=True)
    y1 = sympy.Function("y1")
    y2 = sympy.Function("y2")
    ode = m2*(l2**2)*sympy.diff(y2(t), t, 2) + m2*l1*l2*sympy.diff(y1(t), t, 2) + m2*l2*g*y2(t)
    sympy.Eq(ode)

    L_y = sympy.laplace_transform(y2(t), t, s)
    L_y2 = sympy.laplace_transform(y1(t), t, s) 
    L_ode = sympy.laplace_transform(ode, t, s, noconds=True)
    sympy.Eq(L_ode)


    L_ode_2 = laplace_transform_derivatives(L_ode)
    sympy.Eq(L_ode_2)

    L_ode_3 = L_ode_2.subs(L_y, F)
    sympy.Eq(L_ode_3)
    #print("L_ode_3",L_ode_3)

    kf = {y2(0): -1, y2(t).diff(t).subs(t, 0): 0}
    L_ode_4 = L_ode_3.subs(kf)
    sympy.Eq(L_ode_4)
    #print("L_ode_4",L_ode_4)
    Y_sol = sympy.solve(L_ode_4, F) #kiszamitja az F-t
    #print("Y_sol=", Y_sol)
    y_sol = sympy.inverse_laplace_transform(Y_sol[0], s, t)
    sympy.simplify(y_sol)
    print(y_sol)
    return y_sol

y_sol1=Laplace()
y_sol2=Laplace2()
```

Comment: "My personal problem is that I don't know the way I could solve it with Laplace" - in my opinion, you should write out the math first because, if you don't know what you want to write, Python, or any other programming language, will only get in the way

Comment: You also need to be _much_ more specific about the problem you are encountering when asking questions here — i.e. saying "It doesnt really give me the desired result" to way too vague.

Comment: I would recommend using `dsolve` to solve ODEs rather than Laplace transforms.

Comment: I think you shouldn't try to do the math symbollically. A numerical approach is much more sutiable. Actually the matplotlib docs have something like this. Take a look at [this page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/animation/double_pendulum_sgskip.html).

Comment: At least this question was helpful, I'm reading a (good) book where the derivative substitution routine (`laplace_transform_derivatives`) is bugged, yours is exact and solved my problem.